# Describe Mockito sample code

Tags: mockito

In the http://mockito.org/ website the following sample code is given to describe the usage of the mockito framework. However i am not able to understand what the following code is trying to test. Please comment on the following code as what is it exactly testing. If it is testing the add method of the List, what does it expect?

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

// mock creation
List mockedList = mock(List.class);

// using mock object - it does not throw any "unexpected interaction" exception
mockedList.add("one");
mockedList.clear();

// selective, explicit, highly readable verification
verify(mockedList).add("one");
verify(mockedList).clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you've a test preparation

```
// mock creation
List mockedList = mock(List.class);
```

a test execution

```
// using mock object - it does not throw any "unexpected interaction" exception
mockedList.add("one");
mockedList.clear();
```

and a test verification (without mockito mostly done with something like *assertEquals*)

```
// selective, explicit, highly readable verification
verify(mockedList).add("one");
verify(mockedList).clear();
```

The last block (the test verifaction) is testing, if

- the add method of the mockedList was called with a parameter that equals the String "one"
- the clear method of the mockedList was called

It is just a basic demo of how the interaction with a mocked class can be verified (since you cannot verify the contents of the List because it has been mocked and the calls of `add("one")` and `clear()` don't change the contents of the List).